# Upload duplicate file with different reference column

Tags: 2007

Is it possible to upload the same document but the documents have different reference column in document library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created a new folder for each reference, so user can upload same file but in different folders.

Answer (score 0):

Using default Upload option it is not possible.

You may paste same document using "Open with Explorer" and then check to overwrite it or leave both. It is similar as in windows explorer.

If you want to save in one library same documents without changing its name, upload it to different folders.

Or change its name before uploading.

Comment: how to change the name of file while uploading i just want to add a string in name during uploading. I dont want also to delete the existing file because it was being used by another record.

Comment: Just upload it with unselected checkbox "Add as a new version to existing files", it that case it uploads document with "-copy" string at the end of name. After upload it will gives you a form to fill the properties, in that form you can also change the document name.

Comment: I tried it already to default the checkbox to uncheck, but it prompts me an error that document already exist. How to deal with it? Please bear with me, new to sharepoint development :P

Comment: Actually I don't remember how it was on SP 2007... Could you open you library with Explorer (there are button in library properties "Open with Explorer"), and try to paste you file in that way.

Comment: it will just open a file explorer, not the same on what u mean :)

Comment: But could you check if you can paste the document with the same name to it (yes, in file explorer)? It should promt you that this file is already exist and give an option to overwrite it or keep both.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25313/discussion-between-excaliburcayote-and-martusha).